# How to make text fields to listen for other text fields using data-attributes and Javascript events?

Tags: jquery, events, textfield, onchange, updates

I would like to build an HTML form where it shall be allowed to duplicate a row of fields for new entries or delete such a row to drop its entries by pressing two several buttons for every task. Everytime when a row is added the current total rows count shall be set as value into an associated monitor text field. As this concept shall be used for several more fieldsets within this form there shall be a master text field displaying the overall total value of all the single monitor text fields. For example:

One fieldset refers to all bathrooms in a house. Row 1 would list all items in bathroom 1. After adding a new row for bathroom 2 the user can define all utilities in this bathroom. The monitor shows value 2 for two bathrooms. The master monitor also shows 2.
Another fieldset refers to bedrooms in a house. Same things and behavior here. Everytime i add a bedroom the monitor increments and vice versa. The master monitor now shows the total of the bathrooms monitor and the bedrooms monitor.

All the magic shall of course happen by a Javascript. But i am stuck with the most elegant implementation. My first idea is to assume that for every fieldset a monitor field exists and after adding a new row the button click handler sets the new row count as this fields value. This change should immediately update the overall total value of the master text field. But the button must not know whether its monitor field should propagte to another monitor field. It should not even know whether there is a monitor field watching its actions.

So my second idea is to use data-attributes to define which field shall propagate to which monitor or which field shall listen to which other fields changes based on the event listening concept starting with the master monitor text field to listen for changes with the single fieldset monitor fields. But here is where my imagination and knowledge end. I do yet know that there is jQuerys `change()` method to trigger the change event. However, i can't imagine how to stick these things together.

Can you show me a simple start off of how to build this data-attributes/event-listeners based network with decoupled monitor fields?

Comment: This is a Q&A site :) meaning you should show explains of your problems with actual code.

Comment: `meaning you should show explains of your problems` is exactly the point. My post explains in detail what my problem is. I am stuck with the right implementation and not with finding mistakes from an existing implementation. If this site is not for questions about where/how to start then i wonder what else i should ask to get start off support. Do you seriously want me to post a full HTML form and CSS but Javascript as there is none just to satisfy you for an answer? There are plenty other questions to be found on site asking for where to start without providing any code.

Comment: examples of your code*

Comment: I have no code yet! If this is a problem for you stop wasting your time on my problem and stop acting like the forum police!